# React Sort By Like

Tags: reactjs, sorting

I am trying to figure out how to add an onClick feature that will then sort the likes in descending order. AKA each project has a 'like' button. I want to add another button to the page to allow the user to sort the project likes by descending order.

```
import React from 'react';
import ProjectsListItem from './ProjectsListItem'

const Project = ({ projects }) => {


  const renderProjects = projects.projects.map(project =>
   <ProjectsListItem project={project}  key={project.id}/>

);


return (
  <div className="container">
    <div className="row">
      {renderProjects}
    </div>
  </div> 
);
};

export default Project;
```

Page 2

```
class ProjectsListItem extends Component {

handleOnClick = () => {
this.props.likeProject(this.props.project)
 }

 onClick = () => {
 this.props.sortBy(this.props.project.like)
 } 


render() {
 return(
   <div>
   <div className="col-sm-4">
    <div className="container-fluid text-left">
      <h4> <Link key={this.props.project.id} to= 
     {`/projects/${this.props.project.id}`}>{this.props.project.title} 
      </Link> </h4>
      <h5> {this.props.project.studio}</h5>
      <CounterButton project={this.props.project} likeProject=  
    {this.handleOnClick}/>
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>
  )
 }
 }
  const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
 return {
  projects: state.projects
   }
  }
 export default connect(mapStateToProps, {likeProject}) 
 (ProjectsListItem);
```

Comment: Welcome, I removed the Ruby and RubyOnRails tags because they are not relevant to the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would have to make an event handler such as 
https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html

In this case you would probably want to do

```
onSortClick(e) {
 e.preventDefault();

 this.props.sorted = true
}
```

bind that to your click handler like this:

```
 <CounterButton project={this.props.project} likeProject=  
    {this.onSortClick.bind(this)}/>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Ok I see! Thank you for this. It put me in the right direction.